# How to set default value in select drop down menu in html using Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want that when the page opens the dropdown menu shows some default value like 2001-02 and the Year option(which is currently showing as default) should be in the dropdown list as a disabled option(which not does any task).

**NOTE:- I AM USING `age:''` PROPERTY SOMEWHERE IN MY CODE, SO I CAN'T USE IT AGAIN**

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
    return {
            options: ["1999-00","2000-01","2001-02","2002-03","2003-04","2004-05","2005-06","2006-07","2007-08","2008-09"],
            age:''
            }
         }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div class="custom-select">
    <select class="select" v-model="age">
        <option style="display:none;" selected disabled value="">Year</option>
        <option v-for="option in options" :value="option">{{option}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: preset age with your desired date, sidenote you should compute options, and preset with first or last item in array, will reduce maintenance

Comment: can you please show me what actually you want to say?

Comment: `age:'1999-00'`

Comment: sorry but I am using this `age:'1999-00' `property somewhere in my code, so it is necessary. Do you suggest some other option?

Comment: your using `v-model="age"` for the selects model, I reread your question a couple of times, to disable that option if its preset use the disabled prop `v-for="option in options" :value="option" :disabled="option === age"`

Comment: Ahhh, It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should be the solution:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
    return {
            options: ["1999-00","2000-01","2001-02","2002-03","2003-04","2004-05","2005-06","2006-07","2007-08","2008-09"],
            age:"1999-00",
            }
         }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div class="custom-select">
    <select class="select" v-model="age">
        <option disabled value="null">Year</option>
        <option v-for="option in options" :value="option">{{option}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using age property somewhere in my Vue code so I can't use it. Do you have some other suggestion?

Comment: Can you show the full piece of code (where you are using age), for example on CodePen?

Comment: @AndrewSavetchuk How could it be done to set Year as the first value to be displayed?